# CakePHP - page that accesses multiple tables & categories

Tags: php, database, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm making a site that has a lot of different categories, each with their own controller/model/views.

Example site categories:  Dining, Movies, Nightlife, Sports...etc

My Controllers:  restaurants, theaters, events, articles, cities, users... and more

I also have a site homepage that pulls data from all of them to populate little boxes on the page.  And, each category has it's own homepage that also could pull data from different categories - for instance, on the "Movies" homepage, it might also pull in restaurants and sporting events that are nearby the theaters and maybe a few recent articles from the articles model... etc etc - there is a lot of category-overlap.

How do I set this up?  The sporting event isn't tied to the movie at all, so I can't imagine any hasMany/belongsTo type relationships - but I still need to access the data.  And especially on the homepage, which really has no table at all, but needs to pull data from all of the above.

Comment: Have you considered normalizing the data so all categories are contained in the same model? Is there a specific reason why you don't?

Comment: @cdburgess - it would be very difficult (and not correct imo) to normalize theaters, articles, sports teams, movies, restaurants, events... and more all into one table/model.  Seems backwards logic to me, and a nightmare to maintain.

Comment: If they all have different data, yes. If not, then it's the best way to go. You simply add a column of TYPE or TYPE_ID and reference the table that identifies the type. (`ID, NAME`) This makes it nice because when there is a new type you want to add, there is no additional coding to add the new table, you simply add the type to the database and it is available. Then to get the type, you pass it as a condition on the query. Simple.

Comment: @cdburgess - I understand database layout 101.  These (as I assume you can imagine) have very different data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is too big to cover in its entirety. I'll address accessing multiple models across different controllers. This can be done in several ways.

by relationship:

```
$this->Event->City->find(); // relationship to City exists in Event Model
```

by adding it to the `$uses` property in your controller:

```
var $uses = ('City');
```

by loading into the method as needed:

```
function some_method() {
  App::import('Model', 'City');
  $this->City->find();
```

Each has its own benefits. You should read more about [Models in the CakePHP Book](http://book.cakephp.org/#!/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together). If you have a large amount of relationhships, you should check out [LazyModel](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/Frank/2010/08/10/optimizing-model-loading-with-lazymodel) for lazy loading your models.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to implement `components` to handle the various categories. The component will provide the access for the category box for any given page (which will be different from the category home page).

Then I would implement an element called 'category' that you can pass the information to from the component. I would also make all components export similar data. This will keep it simplified but still provide the flexibility you are looking for.

In summary, create components for each category:

- DiningComponent
- NighlifeComponent
- etc.

Pass the output to the category element to be displayed on the page.

Comment: I think components are going to be the answer I was looking for - but trying them out first to verify - thanks!

Comment: Can the components get data from a database table(s) though?  Ie - on the homepage (and almost all of the category pages), I'd like to have a little calendar box that shows upcoming events from the events table... so - I created a CalendarComponent... but how does that access the events table?

Answer (score 0):

At first glance maybe you don't see another model that is overarching, but the idea that you are calling them "categories" means they have to be a category of something, possibly activities.  The new model may be pretty thin, but I would maybe suspect something like appearance scheduling to be involved with the activity model, so you can give it a beginning and ending publish date.  If you don't want to call it an "activity", maybe something generic like "contentItem" would give you somewhere to control global attributes.  Another exercise would be to compare your existing models and look for duplicate attributes.  What are those duplicate attributes describing?

Comment: I understand what you're getting at, but that would REALLY be a stretch - there are a lot of different things that just really don't have a relationship w/ the other things.  I appreciate your input though, and will think more about it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the loadModel function if there is no relation between two controllers

> $this->loadModel('Foo');
>   $this->Foo->Bar();

When there is a relation of course, you can do

> $this->Foo->Bar->Baz();

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you want

[How to build a dashboard for your cakephp application](http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/12/16/how-to-build-a-dashboard-for-your-application-in-cakephp/)

Answer (score 0):

To understand more about the data models in CakePHP you can use http://cakeApp.com a online schema builder.